# Find Information For Describing A Nuclear Power Plant

Tags: resources, research, setting, inspiration

I want to start my story connecting the government flaws to the main characters life before he was even born. I thought since the settings a somewhat Communist United Soviet United government, A nuclear facility like Chernobyl would be a good scene. I want to describe the insides of the nuclear facility. But how can I find photogrpahy or video of inside of a place that could be your deathbed if you went in to record what is in there? I want to have a "trap" or multipl occur in the plant so I need to know what "host of vicious implements, I can use to exact my pound of flesh" I used HowStuffworks to see how Nuclear Reactions work, and yes I could use the hot water or steam as part of the suffering trap involved, but thats not unique - A lot of places have hot stuff. So how exactly should I learn about what is inside a nuclear facility?

Comment: Wired actually did a piece on Chernobyl in the last year; you could try looking that up.

Comment: A little bit of sneaky advice: If you spent a couple hours researching the subject, 99.9% of your readers spent less. Make something up that sounds believably and doesn't conflict what you know and they will be none the wiser and swallow it happily. As for NPP, scale the human down to size of a rat, then adjust your mental image of the machinery to that scale and rethink dangers. Just think a tiny screw getting into a truck-sized turbine may result in the crew going by car around neighboring villages to seek where the turbine landed...

Comment: The Writers community is currently divided on whether questions like this are on-topic. [This thread](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/20/26) has the details. I would recommend that answers that are more about identifying appropriate resources and less about the details of nuclear power plants would be both more on-topic as well as useful to future visitors.

Comment: @NeilFein: In that case, shouldn't the Q be even more general? Something like: _"How to research top-secret places or settings with not much public documentary material?"_

Comment: Chris, play S.T.A.L.K.E.R.

Comment: @Mussri - You  may be right; please feel free to contribute to the meta discussion on this.

Comment: Thanks wired looks interesting. I will check out stalker. @Niel Fein i understAnd where youre coming from. But, i cant change it now

Comment: @NeilFein Should I make the question more general like Mussri said - ""How to research top-secret places or settings with not much public documentary material?" Then give the example of my specific case?

Comment: @ChrisOkyen - It would make the existing answer irrelevant if you did. I think the question already focuses on how to find information rather than simply asking questions, so it's fine. (My earlier comment was meant to apply towards those who would answer the question.)

Comment: @NeilFein Allright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the outside layout and a small glimpse of the inside of Chernobyl NPP, follow John Smithers' advice: grab a copy of *S.T.A.L.K.E.R. - Shadow of Chernobyl*, read a game guide on how to get the "Good Ending" and play it through. The authors took only minimal amounts of artistic liberties while re-creating the outside layout of the NPP, and while the inside is *technically* nothing like the real thing, it correctly captures the looks and atmosphere.

Still, it's just a small glimpse and heavily influenced by the game mechanics, plus tells very little about the inner workings. If you want some great footage of the insides of Chernobyl NPP, plus quite a bit of backstory and feel of the still active area, try to to somehow obtain a copy of ["Alone in the Zone"](http://www.podniesinski.pl/portal/?p=2901) by Arkadiusz Podniesinski. There are shots all thorough the NPP, outsides, insides, eviscerated 4th block, active control center, a long interview with the staff, and of course a bunch of other objects. Obtaining a copy of the movie might be hard though.

Still, details on inner workings? Actual dangers of active, functioning NPP? I'm afraid this is a wrong place to ask that. I believe while it will be just as off-topic on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), but at least I hope that's where you should  be able to obtain actual pointers to where to ask to get your answers.